# How to pass date object to SOAP request in Worklight Adapter

Tags: soap, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I use Worklight Adapters with HTTP SOAP request to backend service. So, I had several problems:

1. How to use loop (ex. `for`) to create request string in Adapter?.
2. How to pass the date string to request string. (ex. `date` argument has value "`2014-10-12T00:00:00+03:00`");

I has successful tested this request in SoapUI and received right response. When I try to create request dynamically from procedure arguments, invocation result is failed. Instead, when data is written in the request like string, all works well.

```
    var path = '...';
    function procedureName (sessGUID, id, number, date, status) {
        var request =
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soa="http://...">
                <soapenv:Header/>
                <soapenv:Body>
                    <soa:acceptPayment>
                        <id>{ id }</id>
                        <number>{ number }</number>
                        <date>{ date }</date>
                        <newStatus>{ status }</newStatus>
                        <sessGUID>{ sessGUID }</sessGUID>
                        <loginName></loginName>
                        <localRequestTime></localRequestTime>
                    </soa:acceptPayment>
                </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>;

        var input = {
            method : 'post',
            returnedContentType : 'xml',
            path : path,
            body: {
                content: request.toString(),
                contentType: 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8'
            }
        };

        return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all it is not a must to use E4X, at the end you are just sending a string. You can build your string in any way you want.
   If you do want to use E4X you can use `appendChild()` in order to build your SOAP envelope. Create the element you want to loop on and append it to its parent.
2. Did you try var `d = new Date(); var n = d.toUTCString();`?